# How to disable reverse ajax polling in HtmlUnit 2.9 that causes application to hang?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm using the basic ***webClient.getPage*** method to retrieve a page after authentication but this website uses some kind of comet/meteor server to make never ending ajax requests so the *getPage* enters to a loop and i'm getting:

> Jun 22, 2012 3:40:15 PM
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered:
>   'application/x-javascript'.

If i disable javascript all together then i get the source page and it stops hanging:

```
 webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

But then i can't use HtmlUnit features such as clicking buttons that have javascript events.
I figure i'm not the first one that crossed with the issue but i can't seem to find a decent solution out there.

The page i'm trying to connect to is facebook, this is my code:

```
public static void submittingForm() throws Exception {
      //  final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
        webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.setTimeout(60000);
        webClient.setRedirectEnabled(true);
        webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.setUseInsecureSSL(true);

        // Get the first page
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.facebook.com");

        // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
        // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
        final HtmlForm form = page1.getHtmlElementById("login_form");

        final HtmlTextInput textFieldUsername = form.getInputByName("email");
        final HtmlPasswordInput textFieldPassword = form.getInputByName("pass");
        final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByValue("Log In");


        // Change the value of the text field
        textFieldUsername.setValueAttribute("emailhere/username");
        textFieldPassword.setValueAttribute("password here");

        // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
        // And get the cookie set up.
        final HtmlPage page2= button.click();

        //Go to the bob marley fan page
        HtmlPage fanPage = webClient.getPage("http://www.facebook.com/BobMarley");
        webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Get the label that containes the like button from the fan page
        HtmlLabel likeLabel = fanPage.getHtmlElementById("timelineHeadlineLikeButton");


        try{
            // Get the like button
            HtmlSubmitInput likeButton = (HtmlSubmitInput)likeLabel.getLastChild();
            // Press it
            likeButton.click();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }
```

Comment: I didn't see this case yet, in your place i would try with latest svn or build http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingLatestCode.html it helped me a lot to manage buggys javascripts.

Comment: @maxmax didn't work but thanks

Comment: too bad. Is the url public or do you know another one like this ? I'll be glad to help

Comment: @maxmax i edited my question to include the code. i would love it if you could help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this thread is still open and unresolved. For the benefit of those that might run into this issue:

I tried to log in to an internal web site (not open to the web) using HtmlUnit. It hung giving the same message you encountered.

```
Oct 09, 2013 1:39:59 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
```

It went into a loop. This is just a WARNING something that can be turned off. One of the reasons your script hangs might be because it's waiting for some javascript to load.

You have set a connection timeout. Try setting a javascript timeout using:

```
webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(45000);  //Set JavaScript Timeout to 0.75 minute
```

I did the same and it worked for me. It timed out and went on to execute the remaining lines of code:

I got the following output:

```
INFO: Caught script timeout error
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.TimeoutError: Javascript execution takes too long (allowed: 45000, already elapsed: 45001)
................
```

If the unresponsive script is not critical to your login operation , your code will work fine.